# React-Native: packager not detecting images

Tags: image, react-native, packager

I can't figure out how to programmatically add in images in React-Native.  I have a directory, `/img`, full of images, and a json file, `data.json` full of data entries that have corresponding and image file paths:

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "img": "img1.png"
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "img": "img2.png"
 }
]
```

I have loaded `data.json` into a variable with `var data = require('data.json')`, and I can access the image paths normally through `data[0].img`. Also, I can create `Image` tags that display the images through `<Image source={{uri = "./img/img1.png"}} style={styles.img}/>`.

However, when I try to combine the two, with `<Image source={{uri = "./img/" + data[0].img}} style={styles.img}/>`, I get this error: Requiring unknown module "./img/img1.png". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.

I have restarted my simulator multiple times, searched here and the documentation for hours to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two "errors" in your code: object key is not assigned with `=` but with `:`. And you can't combine strings in this case, since AFAIK, there's ultimately used `require()` for images and it doesn't accept anything other but plain strings.

I'd encourage you to do it like this:

```
const assets = {
  img1: './img'+ data[0].img
}

...

<Image source={{uri: assets.img1} style={styles.img}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show local images this way.

What you can do is the following :

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "img": require("./img/img1.png")
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "img": require("./img/img2.png")
 }
]
```

then `<Image source={data[0].img} style={styles.img} />`